# Transferring RFID scanned ID from one webpage to another

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have setup a splash page that detects an RFID input from a scanner and directs the user to a registration page after the input is received. I want that scanned ID number to be available to the registration page so that when form is submitted to my database, the ID number is captured with the other form data. In the javascript file for the splash page I have implemented the code below, where userID is a String.

```
localStorage.setItem('userID', userID);
```

In the javascript file for the registration page I have:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('userID'));
```

However, nothing prints to the console. What am I doing wrong? I have confirmed that the setItem() function is working by printing to the console of the splash page.

Comment: what are the url's for the splash page and registration page.

Comment: I'm testing on my local machine. 
http://localhost:5000/html/registrationSplash.html
http://localhost:5000/html/registration.html

Comment: in browser console check for localStorage and check the userId is there or not

Comment: @Dinesh I'm not sure what you mean "check for localStorage" in the browser. I have the browser console open and there is nothing there.

Comment: @gig6 in console just type localStorage

Comment: After typing localStorage, it appears that it is saving the correct userID.
    Storage {firebase:host:xxxxxxxxxxx-fd036.firebaseio.com: ""s-usc1c-nss-103.firebaseio.com"", userID: "0000000010", length: 2}
Not sure why the console doesn't display on page load...I'm a total newbie with js.